# Oracle - How to use START WITH in loop (hibernate select)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, loops

I am using hibernate for this select:

```
NativeQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("select :id, min(a.time) " +
                        "from table1 a, (" +
                        "   select parentid" +
                        "   from (" +
                        "       select LEVEL, parentid" +
                        "       from table2 " +
                        "       START WITH id = :id" +
                        "       CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR parentid = id" +
                        "   order by level desc)" +
                        "   where rownum = 1" +
                        "   ) b " +
                        "where a.id = b.parentid");
                sqlQuery.setParameter("id", id);
                List<Object[]> list = sqlQuery.list();
```

I need to use this for a lot of ids. Ideally I would pass a list of ids, run that in oracle and return the result. I cannot do that because of the START WITH clause.
This way I send a query to database for each id, which is really slow.

Is there any way to put a list of ids to the query, do this in loop and return back to the application with a list of results?

```
NativeQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery("...?...");
                sqlQuery.setListParameter("ids", ids);
                List<Object[]> list = sqlQuery.list();
```

Edit: I cannot use recursive with, because we use Oracle 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the Oracle specific syntax, but with the SQL standard `WITH RECURSIVE` syntax, you can of course list multiple parameters. Just use the `IN` predicate e.g. for batches of 5 `id IN (:id1, :id2, :id3, :id4, :id5)` and then bind the values with `setParameter("id1", ...)`. If you are interested, you can also formulate this with Blaze-Persistence on top of Hibernate by using the JPA model: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#recursive-ctes

In your case this would look like the following:

```
@CTE
@Entity
public class ResultCte {
  @Id
  Long parentId;
  Long rootId;
  int level;
}

CriteriaBuilder<Tuple> cb = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, Tuple.class);
cb.withRecursive(ResultCte.class)
  .from(Entity2.class, "e2")
  .where("e2.id").in(idList)
  .bind("parentId").select("e2.parent.id")
  .bind("rootId").select("e2.id")
  .bind("level").select("1")
  .unionAll()
  .from(Entity2.class, "e2")
  .from(ResultCte.class, "cte")
  .where("e2.id").eqExpression("cte.parentId")
  .bind("parentId").select("e2.parent.id")
  .bind("rootId").select("cte.rootId")
  .bind("level").select("cte.level + 1")
  .end()
.from(Entity1.class "a")
.from(ResultCte.class, "cte")
.where("a.id").eqExpression("cte.parentId")
.select("cte.rootId")
.select("min(a.time)")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am on Oracle 10, which I believe cannot yet use recursive with :-(

Comment: That's unfortunate. I think the support for that syntax was added in 11g. Anyway, you should really ask your DBA or sysadmin why you are still using a version that is almost 20 years old.